# C printing of string is resulting in weird characters

Tags: c++

I am trying to output an int the following way:

```
void the_int(int i)
{
     int lenghtOfInt = 0;
     int tempValue = i;
     while(tempValue >= 1)
     {
          tempValue/=10;
          lenghtOfInt++;
     }

     int currentDigit;
     char string[lengthOfInt];
     while(i>9)
     {
           currentDigit= i % 10;
           i = i/10;
           char ch = (char)(((int)'0')+currentDigit);

           string[lengthOfInt--] = ch;
     }
     string[lengthOfInt]= (char)(((int)'0')+i);
     function(str); //prints the string character by character
}
```

if i try this function with i = 12 I get à12ç. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, `function` is a **horrible** choice for the name of a function.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: I realize that... it has a long and complicated name and is unimportant to this problem since I have tested it with other strings

Comment: It should print 12 rather than à12ç

Comment: Might have to have a look at how 'function' is working. Have you tried allocating an extra char in your array and null terminating(setting last value to a '\0')?

Comment: Not sure where to begin with this.  Why not just do a printf?  string array is never initialized, so filled w/garbage to begin with.

Comment: Are you aware of itoa function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing beyond the array bounds in the following line.

```
string[lengthOfInt--] = ch;
```

This tries to access index `lengthofInt` which is incorrect.

Now, ignoring the array declaration with a variable,

```
char string[lengthOfInt];
```

declares an array having indices from `0` to `lengthofInt - 1`

Also, depending on how you are printing your string, you might need a '\0' character at the end. Although, if you are going character by character and are sure of your bounds, then it is not needed, but is recommended nonetheless.

Comment: -1: No it most certainly does not. C++ does not have VLAs.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel I dont understand what you are trying to point out.

Comment: Using a variable to declare an array, e.g., `char string[lengthOfInt]` is a gcc extension and is not supported by the standard.

Comment: @adamdunson Ok, so where am i going wrong in my answer ?

Comment: @AshRj: I'm pointing out that your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Join the 21st century and use a `std::string`.

Comment: -1, Its a homework assignment and OP is using C not C++

Comment: @RichardSchneider OP tagged it c++.

Comment: @Non-stop, ur correct and I removed -1.  In my defense, the title said C not C++.

Answer (score 1):

All strings in C must end with a nul byte (0).  So first add 1 to the length of char array you alloc on the stack and then before you print add the nul byte to the string.

I assume this is a homework exercise.  Otherwise, you should just use the `itoa` function.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that you are declaring your array with a variable (you should be using dynamic allocation or at least a constant), `char string[lengthOfInt];` needs to be `char string[lengthOfInt+1];` and you need to `string[lengthOfInt] = '\0';` before the while loop. C strings are NULL terminated.

Additionally, why not just `printf("%d", i);`?